# Firebase Storage CORS Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: firebase, vue.js, cors, firebase-storage, vite

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase Storage. I am getting this error logged to the console in Chrome:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/%22website-admin-c9ce6.appspot.com%22VITE_APP_VERSION%3D0.0.0/o/MYx2YMuRBwTD1YBzm3UgpV4bpMx1%2F7D45367D-6184-415C-BFC2-9FE85B5D031B.jpeg' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

However, I already tried setting the cors policy like this that was in another question on here:

1. Create the cors.json file
2. Add this to the file:

```json
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

3. Run this command: `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://website-admin-c9ce6.appspot.com`

This is the output of the above command:
`Setting CORS on gs://website-admin-c9ce6.appspot.com/...`. I still got the same error logged in Chrome as the image did not appear in the Firebase console.

This is my code where I make the storage calls:

```
const storage = getStorage();

export class StorageClient {
  async uploadFile(file: File) {
    try {
            const fileRef = ref(storage, `${authStore.user!.uid}/${file.name}`)
 const url = await getDownloadURL(fileRef);
 return new DbEditResponse(DbEditStatus.success, url)
    } catch (e) {
        return new DbEditResponse(DbEditStatus.error, 'Error. Did not upload file.')
    }
   
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase CORS error trying to fetch a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78107182/firebase-cors-error-trying-to-fetch-a-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

I too was banging my head on this one. Same error as you with the same cors.json as the OP, I had uploaded files to my bucket at https://console.cloud.google.com/storage and set cors configuration via `gcloud --project=<MY_PROJECT> storage buckets update gs://<MY_PROJECT>.appspot.com --cors-file=cors.json`.

The problem was I still had to go to https://console.firebase.google.com/, click Storage on the side nav and go through the enable storage steps. Then I re-deployed to get my security rules updated. Only then I stopped getting this CORS error.

Answer (score -2):

The issue is in the Vite env variable. In my firebaseConfig I replaced the "storageBucket: VITE_storageBucket" by   "storageBucket: "YOUR-PROJECT-ID.appspot.com" "

Comment: Why not update the environment variable value rather than hard-code the project ID into your firebaseConfig ?