# Firebase CORS error trying to fetch a JSON file

Tags: javascript, firebase, cors, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm currently working on a web application where I need to fetch data from Firebase Storage. However, I'm encountering a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue when trying to access the resource. Here's the error message I'm getting:

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this CORS issue would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
if (user) {
    const filePath = `users/${user.uid}/circuits/circuit.json`;
  
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(filePath);
  
    storageRef.getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) => {
        console.log(url); // logs the URL
        fileManager.loadFile(url); // when I try to load the file I get the CORS error
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error getting download URL:', error);
      });
  } else {
    console.error('User is not authenticated.');
  }
```

I've tried setting the request mode to 'no-cors', but it didn't solve the issue, and I believe it's not a recommended solution.

Comment: => https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Configuring-CORS-on-a-Bucket

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: is this backend code?

Answer (score 1):

CORS error occurs when you are tying to download a resource from cloud bucket from a client domain which is not whitelisted.

To whitelist a domain you can gsutil cli command.

Refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration) documentation.